# Question 10.7 of schaum's outlines linear algebra regarding Invariant Direct-Sum Decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

The following theorem is proposed: let W, W', W",... be subspaces of V with B, B', B'',... bases. V is the direct sum of all W's if and only if the union of all the B's bases is a basis of V. I wonder what is wrong with the following counter example: let W be the subspace of R3 formed by the basis B={(1,0,0),(0,1,0)} and let W' be the subspace of R3 formed by the basis B'={(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}. The union of B and B' forms the canonical base for R3, yet R3 is not the direct sum of W and W', for the intersection between W and W' is not empty.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cL1B.png)

Comment: It should say "the disjoint union", or perhaps "all the $\;B\,'$s bases are disjoint and...". Otherwise, yours indeed is a good counter example.

Comment: The theorem, as stated, is indeed wrong.  Good eye.

Comment: I'm happy my question wasn't pointless nor vain, as is often their fall.

Comment: yet, I wonder how is the solution proposed by the autor wrong. I must confess it is too convoluted for me to understand it (the solution is in the image annexed to the question where it says enter image description here).

Answer (score 1):

I think their proof falls apart when they say "because $B$ is a basis of $V$, $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for each $i$ and each $j$". This is not correct because if, say $w_{11} = w_{12}$, then we can only conclude that $a_{11} + a_{12} = b_{11} + b_{12}$, so uniqueness can fail.